# Parse iOS - How to query PFUser details from another class

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, xcode6

I am trying to write a Parse query for my iOS social app that will show all users that are following the active user. Here is what I have so far:

```
PFQuery *followingUser = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
    [followingUser whereKey:@"Activity" equalTo:@"follow"];
    [followingUser whereKey:@"fromUser" equalTo:self.user];
    [followingUser includeKey:@"User"];
    [followingUser setCachePolicy:kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork];
```

Currently this correctly gives me all the records of the active user following any other users, But this doesn't give me the PFUser details (user profile pic, display name, etc) for the corresponding records. Any ideas on how i can easily draw out the PFUser details in the one query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `User` your reference column to the other users?

Comment: User is the other class. Users are stored in the User Class and follows and likes are stored in the Activity Class. Under the Activity class there is a field called From User which stored the userid pointer is stored. I assumed by using Include Key it would be the equivalent of a join statement.

Comment: `includeKey` Is the name of a column that holds a reference to an object. The query will then retrieve the object pointed to by that reference - so if you had `includeKey` for `fromUser` it will retrieve the properties of the User object referred to by that column - but you don't need to do that because you already have that user object. You need `toUser` or whatever your follower user reference column is

Comment: You will have to retrieve these details at another point by traversing through your array and getting the users from the "fromUser" column. This query will only return "Activity" class objects. Because you used the "includeKey" method you won't have to fetch this data once you create the user object. Also, you should change [followingUser includeKey:@"User"]; to [followingUser includeKey:@"fromUser"];

Comment: yeah im working it a bit backwards on the datamodel, fromUser is the correct field i need, just tried it and got the following error:  OR queries do not support sub-queries with includes'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is some sample code of a query that I used to get all the users being followed, all posts from the users being followed, and all posts from the current user. I hope this helps!

```
// List of all users being followed by current user
PFQuery *followingActivitiesQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:kFTActivityClassKey];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kFTActivityTypeKey equalTo:kFTActivityTypeFollow];
[followingActivitiesQuery whereKey:kFTActivityFromUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
followingActivitiesQuery.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
followingActivitiesQuery.limit = 100;

// Posts from users being followed
PFQuery *postsFromFollowedUsersQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[postsFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kFTPostUserKey matchesKey:kFTActivityToUserKey inQuery:followingActivitiesQuery];
[postsFromFollowedUsersQuery whereKey:kFTPostTypeKey containedIn:@[kFTPostTypeImage,kFTPostTypeVideo,kFTPostTypeGallery]];

// Posts from current user
PFQuery *postsFromCurrentUserQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
[postsFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:kFTPostUserKey equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[postsFromCurrentUserQuery whereKey:kFTPostTypeKey containedIn:@[kFTPostTypeImage,kFTPostTypeVideo,kFTPostTypeGallery]];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: postsFromFollowedUsersQuery, postsFromCurrentUserQuery, nil]];
[query includeKey:kFTPostUserKey];
[query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
```

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't too sure about the whole nesting queries but this has put it into context really well.Thanks man.

Comment: dear SuperKevin,
can you show me the table do you have in parse?