# Get both Parent and Child also with Parse.com for iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've been looking for more than a day, and I can't find answer to the following,

Is there a way to query for a Parent Class and add the associated data from Child Class?

I am doing a voting app, and I am looking for a way to indentify the users who already vote to a particular question. The Question Class is therefor the Parent of Answer Class... Is it the proper way to think ?

Thanks in advance..

Regards, 
Ambroise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would have to query the child class and then you could use the `includeKey` on the pointer from your child class to your parent class and it will include any data associated to the class being pointed to.

EXAMPLE: You would query all answers that point to X question and then you would include the question pointer to get the information associated with the question.

I have an example that I posted a few days ago for a query that uses the include key
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26150007/parse-ios-how-to-query-pfuser-details-from-another-class/26367474#26367474).